# tar - -to-stdout how to restore the content of the stdout and save it to filesystem with the original directory

Tags: performance, tar

I wan't to limit the write speed when tar extract file from `*.tar.gz`.
Now I can extract files to `stdout`, and use the pv to limit the speed, but how can I restore file from the `stdout`?
If there is better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pv` to rate-limit the reading of the tar file, and pipe the output of `pv` to `tar`:

```
pv -L ... tarfile.tar.gz | tar -xvzf -
```

Note that specifying `-f -` will cause `tar` to read from stdin.

That limits how fast the *compressed* tar file is read.  That may not be what you want.  This will limit how fast the *uncompressed* data is fed to `tar`, and may better limit the rate `tar` writes to disk:

```
zcat tarfile.tar.gz | pv -L ... | tar -xvf -
```

Note that this invocation of `tar` does not have the `z` option.